# Automatizing PDF signing via web application

Tags: pdf, ssl, web-applications, windows-authentication, digital-signature

Given a web application, the desired scenario would let the user select their domain certificate and sign the PDF "at the click of a button", like so:

- Open a web page
- Click a `Sign` button
- Certificate selection prompt (screenshot below)
- The page informs the user that the PDF has been signed

[image: Windows Security certificate selection prompt]

**Is there any way this can be performed?**

---

Additional information:

- The web application is running on IIS, in an AD domain, authentication is set to Windows.

What I tried and didn't work:

- Server-side signing of the PDF seems out of the question because it is impossible to send the private key to the server.
- JavaScript's crypto does not have access to the user's personal certificates repository.
- Silverlight doesn't seem to work, as it cannot access System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates (whose method X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection would pop up the Certificate selection).

Comment: Adobe Sign is a web application that will create signed PDFs. The native web application UI is based on HTML5 but the result is a server-side digitally signed PDF. It also has a REST API that will let you integrate it into your own application.

Comment: This soultion does not allow us to sign with the certificate that contains the user's data. We should use the user's domain certificate.

Comment: My suggestion would be to rethink your application. There are reasons why it's not easy for a server to sign a document using a user's private key as Larry explains below. You can do it using an HSM or some other type of secure appliance that stores the certs. If you need to sign the document using the cert that's on the user's machine, your application will need a client-side component even if it's just for signing.

Answer (score 1):

Well PDF and XML signing is standardized under the ETSI standards and accepted as legally binding in the European Union since 2016.
The primary focus for web applications implementation should be usability and as we all know signing with local certificates is not a sexy thing so why make it harder.
I work for company that is focused on implementing both PDF and XML signing component that can be integrated in any web application and is supported on all major browsers Chrome, Edge (legacy and chromium) Firefox, Opera on both Windows and MacOS operating systems. If you are looking a way to implement digital signing within your web app just check or developers portal for our API documentation and how-tos for implementation and trial.
Note: Its license based components but takes that hussle out of maintenance compatibility with browser updates and new signature profiles comming up.

[Link to API documentation](https://developers.nextsense.com)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are commercial products that enable you to do this, including the [DocuSign Digital Signature Appliance](https://www.docusign.com/products/signature-appliance).

However the usual sticking point is that people don't have certificates loaded onto their machine.

And more importantly, such a signature would be weak or not legally binding in many places since certs stored on an ordinary computer are not considered secure.

If your use case is in Europe or some other country that uses a "civil law" system, then you need a secure signature creation device such as a smart card or a hardened appliance such as the DocuSign Signature Appliance.

If your use case is in a common law country such as the US, then you don't need digital signatures--electronic signatures usually suffice and are easier for signers to deal with.

ps. You **can** do server-side digital signature signing if you use a secure appliance. It holds the private keys for your signers.

[I work for DocuSign]

Comment: I was looking into DocuSign. However, the signing is done with a certificate outside of the AD domain. So I can't identify the user that signed.

Comment: I modified the question to reflect my request.

Comment: You can identify the signer through the certificate's metadata. What is your use case? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I need to sign the PDF with the user's domain certificate, all users already have such a certificate. This way, anyone opening the PDF can see the signature and who it belongs to (provided they are logged into the domain).